# Document clustering

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

Are there any Artificial Intelligence algorithms which can be applied to improve Document Clustering results?  The algorithm for clustering can be hierarchical or any other.

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

[The Wikipedia article on document clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_clustering) includes a link to a 2007 paper by Nicholas Andrews and Edward Fox from Virginia Tech called "[Recent Developments in Document Clustering](http://eprints.cs.vt.edu/archive/00001000/01/docclust.pdf)". I'm not sure specifically what you would class as an "Artificial Intelligence algorithm" but scanning the paper's contents shows that they look at vector space models, extensions to kmeans, generative algorithms, spectral clustering, dimensionality reduction, phase-based models, and comparative analysis. It's a pretty mathematically dense treatment but they are careful to include references to the algorithms they talk about.

Answer (score 2):

Clustering is indeed a type of problem in the AI domain. And if you want to go one level down you may say it is in the Machine Learning field. In this sense AI does not improve document clustering, but solves it! [Dumbledad mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10087805/575530) some basic alternatives but the type of data you have each time may be treated better with different algorithm. There are a lot of k-means based approaches for the problem. Careful seeding is needed in such a case. Spherical k-means  (search for the paper of Dhillon) is a simple and standard approach. Other extensions are [k-synthetic prototypes](http://cs.uoi.gr/akaloger/files/2011/11/Document-clustering-using-synthetic-cluster-prototypes-DKE2011.pdf).

Subspace clustering is also a good try and in general if you want to go further than "document clustering" literature check for "clustering in high dimensional and sparse data spaces".